# Returning value from "finish" event after piping data from a read stream to a write stream

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to create a read stream and then pipe the contents of a word document XML file to a write stream and then read from that finished write stream. The problem I am running into is that on the first sequence of reading then writing and then reading I get a `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open]` error. However after this file was created from the first attempt the code runs smoothly and returns the pageCount value as expected.
I have tried to read from the completed file and then return the pageCount value inside of the 'finish' event, but that just leaves me with an undefined returned value. As such, I am not sure what to do.

Any help would be appreciated for this struggling junior.

Update, the following code worked for me.

````
  console.log("unzipping");
  const createWordOutput = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("end is firing");
    fs.createReadStream(data)
      .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
      .on("entry", async function (entry) {
        const fileName = entry.path;
        const type = entry.type;
        const size = entry.vars.uncompressedSize;
        //docProps has the meta data of the document, the word/document.xml is the actual document
        if (fileName === "docProps/app.xml") {
          // console.log(fileName);
          entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./wordOutput")).on("finish", () => {
            console.log("finished writing the file");
            console.log("resolving");
            return resolve();
          });
          //once the piping is completed and the XML structure is fully writen a 'finish' event is emitted. This event accepts a callback. Here I put the cb and call readTheFile on the ./output file. This successfully reads the metadata of each file
        } else {
          entry.autodrain();
        }
      });
  });
  await createWordOutput;

  const pageCount = await readWordFile("./wordOutput");
  if (pageCount === undefined) {
    console.log("PAGECOUNT IS UNDEFINED");
  }

  console.log("logging page count in unzip the file");
  console.log(pageCount);
  return pageCount;
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from `readWordFile`, because it runs before the stream is done.
You need to move reading to the `finish` part

Try this:

```
console.log("unzipping");
let pageCount = "";
fs.createReadStream(data)
    .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
    .on("entry", function(entry) {
        const fileName = entry.path;
        const type = entry.type;
        const size = entry.vars.uncompressedSize;
        if (fileName === "docProps/app.xml") {
            // console.log(fileName);
            entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./wordOutput")).on("finish", async() => {
                console.log("finished writing the file");

                // finished writing, do everything here, and return
                pageCount = await readWordFile("./wordOutput");
                if (pageCount === undefined) {
                    console.log("PAGECOUNT IS UNDEFINED");
                }
                console.log("logging page count in unzip the file");
                console.log(pageCount);
                return pageCount;

            });
        } else {
            entry.autodrain();
        }
    });

};



const readWordFile = (data) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("this is the data that readWordFile received");
        console.log(data);
        console.log("reading word file");
        const XMLData = await fsp.readFile(data, {
            encoding: "utf-8"
        });
        console.log(XMLData);
        const pageCount = XMLData.split("<Pages>")
            .join(",")
            .split("</Pages>")
            .join(",")
            .split(",")[1];
        console.log("getting page count from read word file");
        console.log(pageCount);
        resolve(pageCount);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this response! When I tried this I end up returning an undefined value, which I don't understand either...

Comment: so the ENOENT is gone? where do you get that, from "PAGECOUNT.." log, or the thing that's calling the whole thing..? you might throw in `readWordFile` code if you don't find it, but I think something runs before its time..

Comment: Correct, it's gone there, but I don't return a value. So the 'finish' event is definitely good for waiting till the file writes, but I can't seem to access any variables inside of it.

Comment: you're not returning a promise.. try the updated code

Comment: Updated with the new code and it works, thanks!!!